# Symfony2 controller swap not working

Tags: php, symfony

I need to check my users session on several routes in my project. So I used a controller listener and looked for each request if a controller is instance of a given interface. If that is true i will check the session and if it is not valid the user should be redirected to another controller where the session will be repaired. I used this method the method described [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1975)

This is the code I use:

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $controller = $event->getController();

    if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST === $event->getRequestType()) 
    {
        if (!is_array($controller)) 
            return;

        $controllerObject = $controller[0];

        if ($controllerObject instanceof PreControllerInterface) 
        {
            $result = $controllerObject->initialize($event->getRequest());

            if($result != null)
            {
                $ctrl = new PublicFrontendController();
                $event->setController(array($ctrl, 'identifyAction'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Problem is that I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\Users\Yoghurt\Websites\Mobile\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php on line 189

I think my called controller tries to access a service, but this instance of the controller cannot access the container element because it is empty. Unfortunately I don't know how to fix that. Does anybody knows how I can make that work?

Best regards
Felix

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I realized that it is because you are subclassing `Controller` which is-a `ContainerAware`. You need to give it the 'service_container' service.

The best option is probably to define the controller as a service http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html and then inject it into the class that you have the event handler in.  That is the route I am about to attempt for my code, so I haven't tested it but it should work.  Thought I'd put that out there to help you.